# How to configure Hudson to search all Sonar configuration files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hudson, sonarqube, hudson-plugins

I have all my Eclipse Plug-Ins checked out in **one** Hudson workspace. For every project I defined a sonar configuration file. Actual it is a very easy configuration like this:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=my.project
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# path to source directories (required)
sources=src
```

Now I will configure Hudson to search for every project in my `svn.checkout` folder and start sonar with the defined properties. In the image below you can see my dream configuration:

[image]

The `*` do not work! Is there an other variable to search in all subdirectories for the `sonar.properties` files? Or must I define a build step for each project? Or is there a best practice to analyze big Eclipse RCP projects with Sonar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible with the Sonar Hudson plugin: the "path to project properties" must be a real path, without any wildcards.

You can have a look at how we build and analyse Sonar Eclipse, using Maven and Ant: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and the link. I'll try it the next days and report.